# Is being a full time university student a strong tie to help me get a UK visit visa

Tags: visas, uk, canada, airlines

I want to apply for a UK standard visit visa and I read that I should have a strong tie to my home country that will guarantee my return to my home country when my visa expires.
So i want to ask if being a full time university student is a strong enough tie to help me get a UK visit visa ?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. It depends on the specifics of your case. Would somebody who does **not** think you're honest and reliable come to the conclusion that it makes sense for you to become an illegal immigrant?

Comment: Wanting to take 3-4 months away from your studies outside normal vacation times isn’t consistent with trying to use your studies as evidence of ties you your home country [Can I stay in the uk for up to 3 months when am on a standard visitor visa valid for 6 months](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130084/can-i-stay-in-the-uk-for-up-to-3-months-when-am-on-a-standard-visitor-visa-valid)